# Population or Sample Standard Deviation for a Growing List of Video Game Race Car Performance Stats?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, standard-deviation

I'm making a growing spreadsheet comparing the performance stats of race cars (in the videogame Forza Horizon 4) upgraded to certain performance-indexes (which are basically performance-classes automatically determined by an in-game system). These stats include the averages and **standard deviations** of simulated 0-60mph times, Braking Distances at 60mph, horsepower, weight, etc. What I'm ultimately trying to do here is get the average stats of cars in each performance-class and find out how much different cars in each performance class can be from each other, testing the integrity of the performance-index classification system. I need to know if it would be better to use Population or Sample standard deviation here.

Things to consider here:

- The exact number of cars in each performance class (PC) is not known since many different cars can be upgraded to many different PC's. One could find the exact number of *stock-tuned* cars in each PC, but I'm mostly focusing on the more famous, upgraded cars that are thought to be the best in a PC.
- To ensure consistency throughout the tuning set-ups, I am using a tune-spec calculation tool called ForzaTune 7 to make sure every car is tuned and upgraded to push its highest level of performance in paved road races. I also use another spreadsheet for more detailed comparisons and the internet to find tunes better than mine.
- As I've said, I'm mostly focusing on the higher-end cars in each PC. The number of cars on the list is growing every day I play the game and tune more cars. I can't decide whether or not I should compute standard deviation in terms of a "Population" or a "Sample" of car stats on the list so far.